# Nested 'for' loop in Racket shows error 'not a procedure'

Tags: for-loop, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

I have the following code lines to do bubble sort in Racket. I find the syntax correct but it is still showing error:

```
(define List (list 1 3 5 7 9 2 4 6 8 0))
(define Left  0)
(define Right 0)

(for ([I (range (- (length List) 1))])
  (for ([J (range (+ I 1) (length List))])
    (set! Left  (list-ref List I))
    (set! Right (list-ref List J))

    (when (> Left Right)
      [(set! List (list-set List I Right))
       (set! List (list-set List J Left ))]
    )
  ) 
)
```

The error is:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<void>
  arguments...:
   #<void>
  context...:
   /home/jdoodle.rkt:6:2: for-loop
   /home/jdoodle.rkt:5:0: for-loop
   top-level: [running body]
   eval-one-top12
   begin-loop
   loop
```

Can't guess it out why. I tested it on https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-racket-online but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, sorted it out. I must add the expression `begin` for multiple statements after `when`. Not the double parentheses.

```
(for ([I (range (- (length List) 1))])
  (for ([J (range (+ I 1) (length List))])
    (set! Left  (list-ref List I))
    (set! Right (list-ref List J))

    (when (> Left Right)
      (begin
        (set! List (list-set List I Right))
        (set! List (list-set List J Left ))
))))
```

Or just a series of forms after `when`:

```
(for ([I (range (- (length List) 1))])
  (for ([J (range (+ I 1) (length List))])
    (set! Left  (list-ref List I))
    (set! Right (list-ref List J))

    (when (> Left Right)
      (set! List (list-set List I Right))
      (set! List (list-set List J Left ))
)))
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `begin`. The problem was just the extra double parentheses! In Scheme `(expr)` means "apply this expression as a function". So unless the expression _is_ a function that you want to apply, you must not write `()` around it.

Comment: oh yes, added in the answer